# Gulp command isnt working for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, npm, gulp

Initially I have installed node.js and npm.

And using npm I have installed gulp: `sudo npm install -g gulp`

Here's the output:

```
/var/www/html/laravel$ gulp

Error: Cannot find module 'process-nextick-args'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/laravel/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js:20:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Comment: if you're happy with my answer below, you can accept it :)

Answer (score 3):

You should install all npm deps before running gulp. From the project folder run:

```
npm install
```

Comment: i have installed gulp globally using $npm install gulp -g

Comment: beside `gulp` there's other packages in project, see `package.json` in project folder.

Comment: **package.json** contains {
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-elixir": "*",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0"
  }
}

Comment: great, did you run `npm install` inside project folder?

Comment: Now trying completely again from first :(

Comment: @dumbo you're welcome! don't forget to accept my answer for further readers :)